# Displaying Datagridview Checkboxes state from SELECT Query

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Hello I want to display the result of SELECT query to Datagridview Checkbox Column. What i want is to see corresponding cells with/without checks after getting the results from datareader.

This is my code:

```
 Dim selectQ2 = "SELECT Advance FROM EmpTripTBL WHERE [EmpID] ='" & Form4.empidtxt.Text & "'"
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(selectQ2, con)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    dr.Read()
    If dr.HasRows Then
        Dim advstr As String = dr.Item("Advance")

        //  To add Datagridview Checkbox column
        Dim addcolumn As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
        With addcolumn
            .HeaderText = "Advance"
            .Name = "Advance"
            .Width = 50
        End With
        DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, addcolumn)

        //To check column from database if it's Yes or No
        //Yes = Check
        //No = Uncheck

        If advstr = "Yes" Then
           //Probably the wrong part.

            For x As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2
                DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value = True
            Next
        End If
    End If
```

This is my Database Table:

```
|-- CheckboxColumn --|-- COL 2 --|
     Yes                text1
     No                 text2
     Yes                text3
```

The result what i get from Datagridview:

[image: Datagridview]

Comment: What's the actual problem that you are having?

Comment: the problem is i only get constant result . it's not matching the database.

Comment: Did any answer below solve your issue?

Comment: **1.** Please study up on [SQL Injection](http://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2014/10/prevent-sql-injection-attacks.html). **2.** You only read once: `dr.Read()`, should be in a `while` - see Reza's answer. **3.** If any entry is "Yes", you loop through *all* rows and set them to true. You should only be setting *one* row to true.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood you right so the values of the access database boolean field are true or false...

```
If advstr = TRUE Then
       //Probably the wrong part.

        For x As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2
            DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value = True
        Next
    End If

If advstr = FALSE Then
       //Probably the wrong part.

        For x As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2
            DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value = FALSE
        Next
    End If
```